# Dragging images with mouse, conditionals being ignored in p5.js mouseDragged() function

Tags: javascript, image, drag-and-drop, p5.js

New to javascript. I am trying to use p5.js to allow users the ability to move images on screen when they click on the image and drag their mouse. I have loaded in an image called cart1, with an initial position of (cart1X, cart1Y). Here is my attempt:

```
function mouseDragged() {
    if ((cart1X < mouseX < (cart1X + 50)) && (cart1Y < mouseY < (cart1Y + 50))) {
        cart1X = mouseX;
        cart1Y = mouseY;
    }
}
```

Where the image is 50px by 50px. This does update the position of the cart, but it is like java script is ignoring my if statement, as it updates the position no matter where the user clicks on screen when dragging. I also tried putting the mouseDragged() function within my if statement, but then nothing happens at all. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide possible values of mouseX and mouseY.

Comment: mouseX and mouseY are variables predefined in p5.js, so they are the x and y coordinates of your mouse in pixels, respectively.

Comment: Okay... `console.log` each of the conditions individually to find out which one fails

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that, try using :-

```
 if(mousePressedOver (cart1)){

   cart1.X = mouse.X;
   cart1.Y = mouse.Y;

  }
```